# How to add image alt text this code blog

Tags: wordpress

I have two code blogs
I want it to look like this:

How should the code blog be
Missing alt text
And width height value
 remove url and wordpress url

Sample:

```html
<img class="alignnone" title="Women" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-cR_7KLccvBM/WJ7h-yanzRI/AAAAAAAA6ps/hIk6C6Ha0eQzwIUaFpgYEkA6sY1bheTnwCLcB/s1600/women.jpg" alt="beatiful women" width="650" height="350"
```

```html
<meta itemprop="url" content="<?php if (function_exists('catch_that_image')) {echo catch_that_image(); }?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display your image like the sample then wordpress has two function to use:

If you are wanting to get outside the loop then,

```
wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID), 'thumbnail');
```

inside the loop

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

This will directly create as you sample code. Hope this will work for you

Thank You